# I am having problems setting graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d, rectangles

I am making a simple game where there are two rectangles drawn on the screen and with user input from the keyboard arrow keys one of the rectangles (the player) will move. I have made a `Main` class and a `Play` class which consists of all my game code, this code includes methods such as `init()`, `update()` and `render()`, the `init()` deals with all the initial conditions, the `update()` deals with the movement and key inputs from the input and the `render()` method deals with drawing the stuff onto the screen such as the background and rectangles.

The problem I am having is drawing my rectangles (which are set up with my variables) on my screen by putting them in my render class, my method is set up with `Graphic`s and I have been told I require `Graphics2D` so I am attempting to change my graphics to `Graphics2D` so that I can draw my rectangles.

Here are my Rectangles which have been set up with my variables at the top of my ode:

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
```

and here is my render method where I am trying to draw my rectangles using the graphics2D:

```
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{


    if(rectOne.intersects(rectTwo)){
        g.drawString("Intersect", 100, 100);}


    if(g instanceof Graphics2D){//error: Incompatible conditional operand type Graphics and Graphics2D

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;}//cannot cast from Graphics to Graphics2D

    ((Graphics2D)g).fill(rectOne);//cannot cast from Graphics to Graphics2D
    ((Graphics2D)g).fill(rectTwo);//cannot cast from Graphics to Graphics2D

}
```

The comments next to my code shows the errors that are appearing when I try to use this code. If any more code or information is required from my Play class please tell me and I will post it.

Comment: Do you see these compile-time errors in eclipse?

Comment: Are you sure the `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` classes come from the package `java.awt` or are you picking up classes with these names from some other package? (Maybe one of your own classes is called `Graphics` and this is picked up instead of the one from `java.awt`?)

Comment: There are only 2 class's the main class which is called Game and the Play class which has all the methods listed above in. About the first question, I have imported everything required if that is what you are asking.  @Swanpnil, I see the errors when I hover over the underlined code which is the ones I have added comments to above.

Comment: As per [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8732542/1711796), you may just be missing `import java.awt.Graphics2D`.