# Check if a string is instance of a Class in Java

Tags: java, instanceof

I would like to know how to check if a string is instance of a Class in a Server Side of ServerSocket programm. Α client gives an object of class Myclass1 and the server must check if a string that reads from client is instance of MyClass1 or another class(e.g. MyClass2, String, Integer, etc.)

That is my code:

```
  ObjectInputStream object_input = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
  String string = object_input.readLine();
  if (string instanceof MyClass1){...}
  else if(string instanceof MyClass2){...}
```

It makes an error and I don't know how to solve it. Please, help me

Comment: If it's Java (or any other language), you should add the tag to the list of tag. You can edit your post for that.

Comment: Not sure how a string would be an instance of anything but a string. Maybe I'm missing something because the language is specified..?

Comment: yes sorry. it 's java

Comment: Did you mean check if an object is an instance of a given class? If not, then your question does not sound right; You might want to learn more about Classes in Java

Comment: My error is that I could find if a sting is instanceof Class. I must do that: ObjectInputStream object_input = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream()); Onject obj= object_input.readLine(); if (obj instanceof MyClass1){...} else if(obj instanceof MyClass2){...}

Comment: I think you are looking for something like if string == 'MyClass1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as follows :

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        Object objectFromClient = objectInput.readObject();

        if (objectFromClient instanceof MyClass1) {

        } else if (objectFromClient instanceof MyClass2) {

        }// etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because that code is not logical, the compiler knows that `String string` is an string, that's for sure, so it prevents you from trying to do instanceOf of an string, which is `final` and does not implements `Cloneable`

You can see more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551337/instanceof-incompatible-conditional-operand-types)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to check if a give string (for example: "java.lang.String") represents the valid name of a class in the class loader you could use Class.forName(className). Something like in this example:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(isInstance("java.lang.String")); // will print true
        System.out.println(isInstance("Longssss"));         // will print false 

    }
    public static boolean isInstance(String string) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(string).getName().equals("java.lang.String");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to explore the [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method