# Java - instanceof

Tags: java, extends, instanceof

First off all, I made a "Game-Renderer".

My problem is that, when I need to draw the current Element: I need to know if it's a Rectangle, Circle, or an Image and so on.

My Classes (Rectangle, Circle,...) are extending from Graphic.

```
public class Rectangle extends Graphic {...}
```

And if I want to draw them I look in the List `ArrayList<Graphic>`

```
for(index = 0;index < graphicObjects.size();index++){
    currentElement = graphicObjects.get(index);

    if(currentElement instanceof Rectangle) { // Here is an error.
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle) currentElement;
    // here the drawing.
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping (Goggle wasn't helpful) `:)`

**Edit:**

Error is: "Incompatible conditional operand types Graphic and Rectangle"

And why I need to know the type:
My code:

```
public static Image getImage(Graphics g,int width, int height) {
    int imgWidth = width;
    int imgHeight = height;
    BufferedImage bfImage = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = bfImage.getGraphics();

    for (int index = 0; index < grObjList.size(); index++) {
        Graphic gr = grObjList.get(index);
        if(gr instanceof Rectangle){
            graphics.setColor(gr.color);
            graphics.fillRect(gr.x, gr.y, gr.width, gr.height);
        }
    }
    return bufferedImagetoImage(bfImage);
}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Why would you need to know the type? The point of virtual methods and inheritance is that you don't need to know the type. Just make a draw function and override it in subclasses...

Comment: In general you should follow the practice suggested by nneonneo above and pathfinderelite answer. But in order to solve the mystery in case you use eclipse have a look at the answer with the most votes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551337/instanceof-incompatible-conditional-operand-types

Comment: Check your imports. Most probably you are importing the wrong Rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid using `instanceOf`, have `Graphic` implement an abstract `draw` method.  Then, override `draw` in your `Rectangle`, `Circle`, etc classes.  Then you can do

```
for(index = 0;index < graphicObjects.size();index++){
    currentElement = graphicObjects.get(index);
    currentElement.draw();
}
```

Comment: This version worked best, but didn't solved my question/problem as I needed. Because I don't understood the 'extends': Rectangle extends from Graphic, so Rectangle is a Graphic. And if I put it in the Graphic-List I should check if it is a Rectangle, Cirlce, etc... Maybe I need that for later.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are trying to say that the supertype Graphic is a Rectangle which is not a Rectangle is a Graphic.

So make sure you have a function in the super type  and override it in the subtypes so you dont need to do any casting.